# What are the quantum numbers of Majorana neutrinos?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, neutrinos, majorana-fermions, weak-interaction

I have a question about majorana neutrinos.

Majorana particles are particles that are their own antiparticle.
From this I would argue that they need to have all quantum numbers equal to zero. My question is: what about the weak isospin? This cannot be zero, as neutrinos partecipate into weak interactions.

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say about Majorana fermions:

> *"From this I would argue that they need to have all quantum numbers equal to zero."*

which is not true. Charge conjugation is defined on Dirac spinors as $\psi^c := \mathrm{i}\gamma^0\gamma^2\bar\psi^T$. Being Majorana means $\psi^c = \psi$. While this would imply the spinor has zero *electric charge* (and zero all other $\mathrm{U}(1)$ charges, if there were any, probably), this does not imply anything about the representations of the other gauge groups it transforms in.

Comment: The notion that antiparticles "have all quantum numbers flipped" is an oversimplification.

Comment: Under the standard seesaw mechanism, doesn't "Majorana neutrinos" mean not Majorana bispinors satisfying $\Psi^c = \Psi$, but instead Dirac spinors (which transform nontrivially under charge conjugation) with Majorana mass terms?